# Can't connect github repository using ssh protocol

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'm trying to connect to remote github repository using ssh protocol.
 
After
git remote add origin ssh://username@github.com/foo/project.git
git remote show origin
yields:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

ssh -vT git@github.com log:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/inna/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [999.99.999.9] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/inna/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/inna/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/inna/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/inna/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/inna/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/inna/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/inna/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/inna/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-0de80d89
debug1: no match: babeld-0de80d89
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:hhgkhkjhjkhjkhjkhjkhjkhkjhjkhjkhjk
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/inna/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-dss>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/inna/.ssh/jj
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([999.99.999.9]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = ru_RU.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = ru_RU.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = ru_RU.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = ru_RU.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = ru_RU.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = ru_RU.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = ru_RU.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = ru_RU.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = ru_RU.UTF-8
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
Hi Inna! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3888, received 2484 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 11319.0, received 7231.6
debug1: Exit status 1
```

The https connection to the same project works just fine but I have to log in every time I address the remote repository (by the way, can I outflank it somehow?).
Ssh keys exist and the user have access to them.
Could anyone tell what's the problem please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> git remote add origin ssh://username@github.com/foo/project.git
> ```

This should not use `username` but rather `git`, as in:

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@github.com/foo/project.git
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't add your SSH key to your GitHub account. See this [Doc](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) how to do that.

Comment: Yes, I did add my public key to my git account and it's ok judging by the log.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have added the correct public keys to your GitHub account and that you have the proper rights on the remote repository, my guess is that the issue is related to your private key.

You should ensure that either your private key is named `id_rsa` or that you have the `ssh-agent` running and the key was added it. If you want to run the ssh-agent and add the keys, try the following:

```
$ eval `ssh-agent`
$ ssh-add /path/to/private_key
```